# How can I allow specific URL in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento

My root .htaccess in a Magento store ensures that any visits not written as `(www.)domain.com/correct` will go to our 404 (where "correct" is an existing sub-directory). `(www.)domain.com/admin` is also allowed through.

I now need to also allow some other URLs that do not follow the `(www.)domain.com/correct` form.

Presently the code in the .htaccess is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ go404 [R=301,L]
```

How can I make the following go through as well (ie NOT go404 on me)?

```
www.domain.com/correct/index.php/folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

Comment: the `.htaccess` which you have posted does not seem to allow/disallow anything related to specific sub-directories. Either something else is causing the behaviour you are seeing, or perhaps I don't understand your problem properly. Can you add any additional details?

Comment: Here is the complete htaccess file:

Comment: Please update your question to include it, if it is relevant.

Comment: Will, sorry I couldn't add the htaccess file. It is too long for the comment window. How can I link a text file so you can see it?

Comment: editing your question would give you a much larger limit than adding a comment. Failing that, a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) might be appropriate. Note that a "complete" htaccess file may be too much information, but perhaps we can guide you towards editing it down to the relevant sections once we see it. Right now, I'm not even sure what the question is.